Why is LyX loading `units`?
I have a rather long document written with LyX and it is doing \usepackage{units}. I don't know why it is being loaded and I would like to get rid of this package. How can I track why it is being loaded? Or how could I tell LyX not to load it? I am using LyX Version 2.4.1 (Monday, July 1, 2024)
in Fedora 40.

The linked question have not the answer, but the opposite problem. The answers is that units is loaded because you are using some  \nicefrac or \unitfrac  or \unit in math mode. And the question is why this bother you.

Thanks, I was having a lot of issues installing that package. Finally I managed to do it.
